# Switching between Bluetooth headsets during Audio Session in iOS?

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming

Assuming a user has multiple bluetooth headsets attached, and an audio session is running (playing  something through one of the headsets). Is there a way to get the list of attached bluetooth headsets (maybe using the External Accessory Framework?) and switch the audio session to the other headset?

Answer (score 2):

Replying to myself for anyone else looking for the same. Basically, you can't *just* display the audio source selector (that I can find). But you can display the MPVolumeView, which will include an Audio Selector button if there is a bluetooth device paired. Try:

MPVolumeSettingsAlertShow(); //Needs #import